# Como unir e normalizar dados do Google Trends no R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, dataset, internet

Em minha pesquisa, compararei o interesse público ao longo do tempo em alguns termos, e para isto estou utilizando o pacote do R `gtrendsR`. Pretendo comparar um total de nove palavras-chave, o que extrapola o limite permitido pelo Google Trends (que é cinco). Para contornar essa barreira, fiz dois diferentes conjuntos de buscas, cada qual contendo cinco palavras-chave, e cada busca incluiu o termo com maior volume de pesquisas em relação aos demais. Esses são os comandos do R que utilizei:

```r
library(gtrendsR)

# Definindo os termos de pesquisa:
  
keywords_1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

keywords_2 <- c("A", "F", "G", "H", "I")

country <- c('BR') #Definindo o Brasil como o país-alvo.

time <- ("2011-01-01 2021-12-31") #Estabelecendo o período.

channel <- 'web' #Definindo a fonte dos resultados.

# Fazendo as buscas:
    
dados1 <- gtrends(keywords_1, gprop = channel, geo = country, time = time, category = 0)
    
dados2 <- gtrends(keywords_2, gprop = channel, geo = country, time = time, category = 0)
```

Neste ponto, minha dúvida é como posso unir `dados1` e `dados2` em um só *dataset*. Eu compreendo que todos os dados devem ser normalizados em relação ao termo com maior volume de buscas (`A`), mas como posso fazer essa normalização no R?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O segredo aqui é descobrir onde está a informação que te interessa. Para saber disso, verifique os nomes do que está dentro das listas `dados1` e `dados2`:

```r
names(dados1)
#> [1] "interest_over_time"  "interest_by_country" "interest_by_region" 
#> [4] "interest_by_dma"     "interest_by_city"    "related_topics"     
#> [7] "related_queries"    
names(dados2)
#> [1] "interest_over_time"  "interest_by_country" "interest_by_region" 
#> [4] "interest_by_dma"     "interest_by_city"    "related_topics"     
#> [7] "related_queries"
```

O que realmente importa é o conteúdo presente em `interest_over_time`. O restante pode ser ignorado para a tua aplicação. Como o termo `A` é o termo de maior procura, os resultados de ambos data frames `dados1$interest_over_time` e `dados2$interest_over_time` estão normalizados em relação a `A`. Sendo assim, basta

1. remover as observações referentes a `A` em `dados2$interest_over_time`;
2. juntar as linhas de `dados1$interest_over_time` com o que sobrou de `dados2$interest_over_time`

Minha sugestão de código para fazer isso é a seguinte:

```r
dados1_interest <- dados1$interest_over_time
dados2_interest <- dados2$interest_over_time

dados_finais <- 
  dados2_interest |> 
  filter(keyword != "A") |> 
  bind_rows(dados1_interest)
#> Error in `bind_rows()`:
#> ! Can't combine `..1$hits` <character> and `..2$hits` <integer>.
#> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Perceba que deu errado. Veja o output abaixo para entender porque isso acontece:

```r
glimpse(dados1_interest)
#> Rows: 660
#> Columns: 7
#> $ date     <dttm> 2011-01-01, 2011-02-01, 2011-03-01, 2011-04-01, 2011-05-01, 2011-06-0…
#> $ hits     <int> 51, 55, 61, 59, 61, 57, 54, 64, 61, 65, 66, 56, 54, 60, 59, 62, 61, 64…
#> $ keyword  <chr> "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", …
#> $ geo      <chr> "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR"…
#> $ time     <chr> "2011-01-01 2021-12-31", "2011-01-01 2021-12-31", "2011-01-01 2021-12-…
#> $ gprop    <chr> "web", "web", "web", "web", "web", "web", "web", "web", "web", "web", …
#> $ category <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0…

glimpse(dados2_interest)
#> Rows: 660
#> Columns: 7
#> $ date     <dttm> 2011-01-01, 2011-02-01, 2011-03-01, 2011-04-01, 2011-05-01, 2011-06-0…
#> $ hits     <chr> "51", "55", "61", "59", "61", "57", "54", "64", "61", "65", "66", "56"…
#> $ keyword  <chr> "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", …
#> $ geo      <chr> "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR", "BR"…
#> $ time     <chr> "2011-01-01 2021-12-31", "2011-01-01 2021-12-31", "2011-01-01 2021-12-…
#> $ gprop    <chr> "web", "web", "web", "web", "web", "web", "web", "web", "web", "web", …
#> $ category <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0…
```

Isso ocorre porque a coluna `hits`, para `dados1_interest`, é do tipo inteiro, enquanto essa mesma coluna para `dados2_interest` é do tipo caractere. Há uma explicação para isso: alguns hits do termo de procura `H` deram o resultado `<1`, transformando-o assim em algo que não é numérico. O que sugiro fazer aqui é

1. converter os resultados `<1` para 0;
2. transformar a coluna `hits` em numérico;
3. proceder com o primeiro algoritmo que sugeri

Juntando isso, no final temos

```
dados_finais <- 
  dados2_interest |> 
  # remover observacoes A 
  filter(keyword != "A") |> 
  # transformar `<1` em 0
  mutate(hits = ifelse(hits == "<1", 0, hits)) |> 
  # transformar hits em numerico
  # (daria pra ter feito na linha de cima, mas
  # preferi fazer separado para ser didatico)
  mutate(hits = as.numeric(hits)) |> 
  # juntando o resultado com dados_1
  bind_rows(dados1_interest)
```

Pronto. Agora o objeto `dados_finais` possui as informações desejadas com os 9 termos de busca de interesse, assumindo que para os fins desejados, `<1` possa ser considerado como 0.

Comment: Marcus, muitíssimo obrigado mesmo, me ajudou bastante! Só fiquei em dúvida em uma coisa: e se, além de `interest_over_time`, eu também quiser incluir as demais informações? Ao unir os dois *datasets*, as demais informações precisam ser ignoradas mesmo?

Comment: Depende. Essas informações são realmente importantes? Note que a estrutura de dados original resultante do comando `gtrends` é uma lista com 7 data frames. Dessa forma, as características particulares de cada um deles devem ser consideradas na hora de juntar os resultados. Entendi que a pergunta original só estava preocupada com os hits, então ignorei os outros data frames. Mas acredito que seja possível generalizar o código que escrevi para ser utilizado outras seis vezes, para cada um dos outros data frames.

Comment: Entendi. Realmente meu foco está nos hits, mas tentarei generalizar os comandos para os demais dados. Mais uma vez, obrigado demais!